# +(void)initialize thread safety

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

I am doing some initialization of static variables before any init method is actually called. Here is the code:

```
+(void)initialize{

    if(sShipsDefaults == nil){
        //initialize static variable called sShipsDefaults
    }
}
```

What I can see is that initialize is called only once,lazily, when first instance of class is created, which is desired behaviour.

The part where I check is sShipsDefaults is nil is because even initialize is called once per class, it is also called once per subclass. So if I have Ship class and EnemyShip class which subclass the Ship, then initialize is called twice (once per each class at first creating of it's objects).

Now let's get back to the question...Does initialize do locks like dispatch_once_t (is it thread safe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if initialize is called from a second thread while the first thread is in it then the runtime will block the second thread while the first one finishes.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

You can also put your initialization inside a check for `if (self == [Ship class])` so that it won't be run multiple times when any subclasses have their initialize methods called.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's what I was trying to find out!